# 2 different queries same TextBoxes with VBA code

Tags: sql, ms-access

It is possible to place the result of a query with columns in a form to textboxes with sql code?

Text fields already have a query but when “texto689” is not 0 I want the system will pre populate these fields based on a secondary query.

What I have so far is:

```
' TEST MULTI QUERY
Private Sub Texto689_LostFocus ()
If Not IsNull (Me.Texto689) Then
DoCmd.OpenQuery "CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS"

'Write the result of the query in the textbox specifies
Me.Combinação65 SELECT [CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS] .MARCA FROM [CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS] (is giving error)

End If
End Sub
```

this applyes when i don't need previous data. i use it to insert the car in the sistem. it does combine brand and model, ex. if you choose audi only shows audi models. and it's ok!

'Macro code field mark
field mark is to source `TBLMARCA.MARCA SELECT FROM TBLMARCA;`

```
'Source code macro field model
SELECT TBLMODELO.MODELO, TBLMODELO. [YEAR START], TBLMODELO. [YEAR END], TBLMODELO. [Num doors] FROM WHERE TBLMODELO (((TBLMODELO.MARCA) = [Forms]! [INSERT ORDER]! [Combinação65])) ;
```

here everything is functional but wanted for an after update command to do a different query for these same fields ... the query will have to search the same data but the query "CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇA" and complete only the query results of "ELV consultation insert pieces." it is possible to activate a second query on the same textbox or you must be a code as I wrote the first lines ..... any ideas?

```
TRANSLATE
“CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇA” – QUERY INSERT PART
TBLMARCA – TABLE OF BRAND
TBLMODELO- TABLE OF MODEL
```

Comment: Does Texto689 have a recordsource?

Comment: not it have a control source, but that part is running fine.
i need that number to run a query and update the "combination65" and combination "69"  based in the results of the query.
If i do not enter anything in texto689 i want it to make the regular query of:
"Combination65" - SELECT TBLMARCA.MARCA FROM TBLMARCA

"COMBINATION69" - SELECT TBLMODELO.MODELO, TBLMODELO. [YEAR START], TBLMODELO. [YEAR END], TBLMODELO. [Num doors] FROM WHERE TBLMODELO (((TBLMODELO.MARCA) = [Forms]! [INSERT ORDER]! [Combinação65])) ;

Do you understand my needs?

Comment: I think you'll need to use VBA. Use a recordsets to pull the queries you want. evaluate the data using iif or switch, and write the value to the field in VBA.

Comment: Gene could you put some example of it.
I need to find out what command use in code to put the query table data to the specified textbox....
If you thing that will be better to record a video to show my need say so, that i record one.

Im trying this code with no result
[Private Sub Texto689_LostFocus()
If Not IsNull(Me.Texto689) Then
DoCmd.OpenQuery "CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS"
DoCmd.RunSQL (sQLString)
ME.Combinação65 = "CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS".MARCA FROM "CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS"
End If
End Sub]

Comment: @Gene if you want a video i can post it

Answer (score 0):

Use DLookup:

```
Private Sub Texto689_LostFocus ()
    If Not IsNull (Me!Texto689.Value) Then
        Me!Combinação65.Value = DLookup("[MARCA]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem... I have another doubt that i think that you can help me out.
In this form i have a textbox called "Texto694" that is the number of the part is connected with a table called "TABELASDEPRODUTOS".
I have the first collumn as key collumn and it is a number automaticly.
I need it to show up as soon as i dirt that specific form.
How can i do it? Im new to this forum. Do you think that i need to put this question in another part?

Comment: Yes, raise a new question giving the details and your coding attempts. And mark the answer here for the benefit of later visits.